# How can I implement feature of search like below image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

[image]

above images are example of Gmail application.

what I want is that,

**Image 2** - I want to show suggestion list like this and when user click on that suggestion it has to navigate next view according to that search value

**Image 3 A** - 
(before typing) When I click on search bar button, like this view I want to show, also I want to show segmented control like shown in the image.

**Image 3 B** -
When a user starts typing according to search value data has to be displayed on table view.

I do not know in detail about table view and its feature. I want to learn that how to implement this feature in iOS.

Anybody can help me to implement this functionality.

Comment: Have you sweeped through cocoacontrols.com and cocoapods.com? they will have libraries instead of reinventing wheels

Comment: Search for AutoComplete UITextfield in cocoaControls OR cocoaPods

Comment: [search results controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618649-searchresultscontroller)?

Comment: I implemented search bar and currently search results are showing in same tableview.

Comment: Now, what I want is that, I want to show results in another table view and suggestion list shown like Image 2.

Comment: You can get some idea from here- https://medium.com/@satindersingh71/uisearchcontroller-with-scope-filter-8195f6a11eff and https://medium.com/@PavelGnatyuk/large-title-and-search-in-ios-11-514d5e020cee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**: Simply create a navigation button of search

```
    UIButton *searchButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [searchButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(searchButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [searchButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 35, 35)];

     UIView *rightBarButtonItems = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 76, 32)];
    [rightBarButtonItems addSubview:searchButton];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightBarButtonItems];
```

**Step 2**: After that give action to it, write code for navigating next view

```
- (IBAction)searchButtonClicked {

   SearchViewController * search=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchViewControllerId"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:search animated:YES];

    }
```

**Step 3**: Take one text field and segmented control like below screenshot and add 2 table view below a segmented control and write code.
[image]

```
// This method used to allow select segmented button multiple times (multi-select segmented control)

-(void)setMultiSelectControl:(MultiSelectSegmentedControl *)multiSelectControl{
    _multiSelectControl = multiSelectControl;
    self.multiSelectControl.tag = 2;
    self.multiSelectControl.delegate = self;
}

-(void)multiSelect:(MultiSelectSegmentedControl *)multiSelecSegmendedControl didChangeValue:(BOOL)value atIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

if(index==0)
    {

    _multiSelectControl.selectedSegmentIndex=0;
    _tableview1.hidden=NO;
    _tableview2.hidden=YES;

    [_seachTextField resignFirstResponder];

    // your code

}

if (index==1) {

    _multiSelectControl.selectedSegmentIndex=1;

    _tableview1.hidden=YES;
    _tableview2.hidden=NO;

    [_seachTextField resignFirstResponder];

     // your code

}

}
```